# facebook authentication using actionscript

Tags: authentication, permissions, facebook-actionscript-api, facebook-checkins

I am trying to use actionscript 3.0 API for Facebook authentication. I am able to authenticate successfully but I need user email id. Can some one provide me example of how to get details with additional permission. I presume that you can get user email information using additional permissions and not basic authentication permissions.

Regards.
Dilip

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet will ask for the Facebook's user primary email.

```
Facebook.login(yourLoginCallbackFunction, {scope: "email"});
```

This URI explains this particular permission: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/

There are many other types of permissions, look here for more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/permissions-login-dialog/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the login, you have to ask permissions like this way:

```
var permissions:String = "youFirstPermission,yourSecondPermission,yourThirdPermission...";
Facebook.login(callBackFuncion, {scope:permissions});
```